# Problema con desplazamiento horizontal del scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, frontend, scrollbar

Estoy creando una web, y quiero que en determinada sección, el código haga que la dirección del scroll pase de vertical a horizontal. El problema está en que aún no he terminado de llegar a la sección totalmente y ya empieza a alterarse el scroll del mouse. Esto provoca que la sección se vea hasta la mitad solamente.

```
<script>
    var swiper;
    var previousProgress = 0;
    var swiperContainer = document.querySelector('.swiper-container');

    function initSwiper() {
        swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            direction: 'horizontal',
            slidesPerView: 'auto',
            mousewheel: true,
            freeMode: true,
            scrollbar: {
                el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
            },
            freeMode: true,
            freeModeMomentum: true,
        });

        swiper.on('reachEnd', function() {
            if (previousProgress < swiper.progress) swiper.slideTo(0);
        });

        swiper.on('reachBeginning', function() {
            if (previousProgress > swiper.progress) swiper.slideTo(swiper.slides.length - 1);
        });

        swiper.on('progress', function() {
            previousProgress = swiper.progress;
        });
    }

    // Inicializa el swiper sin el desplazamiento del ratón
    initSwiper();
    swiper.params.mousewheel.enabled = false;

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        var rect = swiperContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (rect.top >= 0 && rect.bottom <= window.innerHeight) {
            if (!swiper.params.mousewheel.enabled) {
                // Destruye el swiper y lo reinicializa con el desplazamiento del ratón
                swiper.destroy();
                initSwiper();
            }
        } else {
            if (swiper.params.mousewheel.enabled) {
                // Destruye el swiper y lo reinicializa sin el desplazamiento del ratón
                swiper.destroy();
                initSwiper();
                swiper.params.mousewheel.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías intentar agregar un [repro]? (con el botón que indica `<>`). Como es JS, es posible intentar reproducir el problema en la pregunta misma. Si lo haces, no olvides agregar la librería relacionada.

Comment: Estoy usando Swiper.js